# How do I start cygwin with a specific command?

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, cygwin

I want to start Cygwin and it should instantly connect to some server:

```
$ ssh user@1.1.1.1
```

for example, how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a Windows shortcut with the target set like so (and an icon of your choice):

```
C:\cygwin\bin\ssh.exe user@1.1.1.1
```

Or, for better terminal emulation than in the default console window, run it in [mintty](http://mintty.googlecode.com), setting the shortcut target like this:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe /bin/ssh user@1.1.1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Make that the last line of your `.bash_profile` or `.profile`

Comment: Not a good solution, because it stops you from running a local bash session. Also, all the stuff in bash startup files such as `/etc/profile` still gets run, which is a waste of time if you're just gonna ssh somewhere.

Comment: Use this for setup  though, e.g. I use "export DISPLAY=:0.0"  here to setup gitk